# Where is wrong cause "Gas limit set dangerously high"?

Tags: solidity, remix

**Problem:**

My smart contract sendTo function send ETH to payee. Whenever I use Metamask to send some ETH to payee it shows "Gas limit set dangerously high", even I comment out "isOwner" .

**Smart Contract**

```
contract Payment {

    event PaymentLogger(
      address _payee,
      uint _amount,
      uint _payeeValue
      );

    // address private _owner;

    // modifier isOwner {
    //     require(_owner == msg.sender);
    //     _;
    // }

    // function Payment() internal {
    //     _owner = msg.sender;
    // }

    function sendTo(address _payee, uint _amount) public payable {
      require(msg.value >= _amount);
      _payee.transfer(_amount);
      PaymentLogger(_payee,_amount,msg.value);
    }
}
```

**Web3js**

```
   $("#sendToButton").click(function() {
        heavengame.sendTo($("#payee").val(), web3.toWei($("#amount").val(),'ether'), (err, res) => {
            if (err) {
                $("#loader").hide();
                console.log(err, result);
            }
        });
    });
```

[image]

**Correct code**

```
$("#sendToButton").click(function() {
    heavengame.sendTo($("#payee").val(), web3.toWei($("#amount").val(),'ether'), {value: web3.toWei($("#amount").val(),'ether'), gas: 1000000},(err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
});
```

[image]

Comment: Obvious question: did you try a lower gas limit? Even if your gas price is low, it's just complaining about your gas limit. I don't think it has anything to do with your contract per se.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your javascript is not setting a gas limit on the transaction so is picking up an unnecessarily high default.    Try setting the `{ gas: ### }` parameter to something lower, like 300000.

Comment: Thank you very much!
But what is meaning of "value"? I set _amount already...

Comment: You set the gas to 1000000 but you are still getting the prompt with same gas limit displayed in the screen shot above?

Comment: MateMask of fixed code was updated.

Comment: Okay, so it looks like setting the gas parameter fixed your "Gas limit set dangerously high" problem.  Do you still have a problem?